# balacing scales of two different plots in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I made a gnu script to plot graph

my script

```
set size square
plot "./points.dat" using 1:2 pt 7 ps 1
replot "./circle.dat" using 1:2:3 with circles
```

points.dat

```
1.000000 -1.000000
-1.000000 1.000000
-1.000000 -1.000000
1.000000 1.000000
```

circle.dat

```
0.000000 0.000000 1.414214
```

according to data-points all points must be in circle but graph shows points outside the circle

Can someone please help me .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem**

With `set size square`.  That causes the length of the `x-axis` and the length of the `y-axis` to be the same *on the "canvas"*.  By that I mean that if you were to print your plot on a piece of paper and measure the x-axis and y-axis with a ruler, you would get the same length.  now, if we look at the documentation for circle objects (`help circle`) we see:

> Any disparity between the horizontal and vertical scaling will be corrected for so that the result is always a circle.

When gnuplot is auto-scaling your graph, for some reason it doesn't autoscale x and y the same (probably due to the aspect ratio of the terminal).

**The solution**

Gnuplot's `set size` has a way to make sure that 1 unit of distance on the `x-axis` takes the same amount of space as 1 unit of distance on the `y-axis`.  The key is to use:

```
set size ratio -1
```

rather than `set size` square.  An alternative solution is to continue using `set size square` but to set the `xrange` and `yrange` explicitly to the same thing:

```
set xrange [-1.25:1.25]
set yrange [-1.25:1.25]
set size square
plot "./points.dat" using 1:2 pt 7 ps 1
replot "./circle.dat" using 1:2:3 with circles
```